# Bootstrap Fields Odd Looking

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

My fields look very odd for they are huge field inputs and take up the whole screen. I am afraid I am not following best practice with my coding. Also, when I input the wrong username and/or password it just turns green and makes no sense.
**Goal:** Better styling of fields and to make error messages more visible.

**Python File:**

```
class LogInForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=10)
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

**HTML File:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1><font size="275">Log In</font></h1>
</div>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

{% if not isUserLoggedIn %}
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Wanting to Test?!</strong><br>
  Username: king<br>
  Password: test123
  </div>
{% if loggedIn %}

<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">

Congratulations, you've logged in! Now redirecting you to the homepage...
</div>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://localhost:8000/">
{% else %}


{% load bootstrap3 %}
<form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xlarge"><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Login</button></div>

</form>
    <div class="col-md-6 column">
<form action="../../"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xlarge"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cancel</button></form>
{% endif %}
{% else %}
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
You're already logged in!
</div>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</form>
```

**Current**
[image]
*Possible Fix (But no something I want to use for I would have to manual create error cases)*

1. Render your form fields manually (@Selcuk)

> ```
> <form class="form-horizontal" id="LoginForm" method="post" name=
> "LoginForm">
>     {% csrf_token %}
>
>     <div class="input-group">
>         <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
>         <input class="form-control" name="{{ form.username.html_name}}"
>         placeholder="Username" type="text">
>     </div>...
> </form>
> ```

Comment: You can make your fields narrower by wrapping them inside a `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">`, for example. If you need exact control of your HTML, better stick to my second suggestion.

Comment: With your second suggestion I would have to create error cases for each error. For example if email field does not have @ then error out, correct? It seems like it would be a ton of work? Would there be a way to have the fields to look like input-groups? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: No, you just print the error messages raised by the form, you don't have to _check_ for errors yourself. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: Seems like a lot of work and I am not to familiar with this. Mind if I could get an example I could test for my username?

Answer (score 1):

The `form-control` class you add to your input tags is causing the boxes to go full width like that.

> All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with
>   .form-control are set to `width: 100%;` by default. Wrap labels and
>   controls in `.form-group` for optimum spacing.
>
> Via- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Thanks! So would you recommend 'form-inline'?

Comment: Since the input boxes are not on the same line (or are you going for that??), I wouldn't recommend going with `form-inline"

Comment: Do you just want to remove the 100% width or are you going for a more custom look to your boxes. If it's the altter, I would recommend creating a new id or class and styling it yourself using css